# Как правильно пользовать os.system при вызове sudo. Как в python реализовать еще и ввод пароля

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, sudo, subprocess

вот например: я хочу через python запустить консольную программу:

```
os.system('sudo apt-get upgrade')
```

и у меня попросят пароль. Как решить эту проблему с паролем. Вот например:

```
import os
comand = 'sudo apt-get upgrade'
pass = 'pass'
```

продолжите дальше

И да, если вы предложите делать всё через написание кода bash, то напишите как сделать так, чтобы запускать этот код на python и python программа не тормазило (что-бы программа ничего не ждала и GUI не зависало)

Comment: при желании можно [в sudo передать пароль через стандартный ввод](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23692520/4279), но стоит заметить что [это плохой подход](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24257940/4279). Вместо этого, организуйте работу так, чтобы не приходилось в скрипте пароль указывать (как именно это лучше сделать, зависит от конкретной задачи).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После несколько дней исследования я написал вот такой код:

```
def update():
    sudo_password = '*********************'
    command1 = 'apt-get update'.split()
    command2 = 'apt-get upgrade'.split()
    p = Popen(['sudo', '-S'] + command1, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    p.communicate(sudo_password + '\n')
    p1 = Popen(['sudo', '-S'] + command2, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    p1.communicate('y\n')
```

Это функция выполняет проверку обновление на компьютере и если обновления есть, то обновляется.